# is the speed of the second fan normal?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion, speedfan

I am using SpeedFan to see the fan speed.
My laptop is HP Pavilion - 14-ce3009ne.

The speed of the second fan does not look normal. it does not exceed 100 rpm. If this normal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your device has a second fan? That the used fan control chip has two ports does not mean that there are two fans attached to it? Typically notebooks only have one fan (if they have a fan at all).

Comment: I am not sure. I thought fan 2 on speedfan means it has two fans.